# How To Replicate This UIPageControl Look?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipagecontrol

I want to replicate the functionality of this view in this app.

It has a UIPageControl at the bottom with 3 views that only changes the view at the bottom, and not the whole view.

Any basic advice on how to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, UIPageControl simply sends events informing you to change a page...

I would place the bottom view in a UIScrollView (that in turn would contain the 3 views you want to alternate), and when the user clicks the UIPageControl, you would set the contentOffset of the UIScrollView.

Makes sense?

Comment: Probably you want to set the pagingEnabled of that UIScrollView to YES as well :)